# PHP5. Two ways of declaring an array as a class member

Tags: php, class, constructor, initialization

When declaring an array as a class member, which way should it be done?

```
class Test1 {
    private $paths = array();

    public function __construct() {
        // some code here
    }
}
```

or

```
class Test2 {
    private $paths;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->paths = array();
        // some code here
    }
}
```

Which one is better in terms of good practices and performance? What would you recommend?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd suggest doing this when declaring a class variable. A constructor can be overriden in extending classes, which might result in E_NOTICEs or even E_WARNINGs if any of your functions depend on this variable being an array (even an empty one)

Comment: Yes, this does matter! As PHP5 documentation states: 'Parent constructors are not called implicitly if the child class defines a constructor'.

Comment: "I'd suggest doing this" when the OP asks an either/or question?  What is "this"?  Doing it in the constructor or as part of the declaration?

Comment: @Adam: It was clear for the OP what it means. Maybe because he read the entire sentence.

Comment: It was clear what the OP meant but not what the answer meant.  It is possible to work out that you probably mean the first alternative but it is far from clear, in my opinion, hence the comment.  In general if the question is "Should I do A or B?" then the answer should be "Do A because..." not "Yes because...", even if it is possible to work out from the "because" that you suggest doing A.

Comment: @Adam Dude, the question is 'should I do it in constructor or while declaring a variable?' and the answer is 'do it while declaring a variable'.

Comment: OK.  Now I understand what you mean.  My interpretation was that either way you are declaring a class variable so which of the two alternatives was "this".  But I see your point. I still think "Assign the array when declaring the variable" (or better simply quote the "private $path = array()") is clearer. Tried to remove the downvote but it won't let me anymore...

Answer (score 8):

If you are going to populate your array dynamically during initialization, do it in the constructor. If it contains fixed values, do it in the property declaration.

Trying to populate an array dynamically (e.g. by using the return value of a certain function or method) within the declaration results in a parse error:

```
// Function call is not valid here
private $paths = get_paths();
```

Performance is not a real concern here as each has its own use case.

Answer (score 6):

In general, because I write mostly in other languages besides PHP, I like to declare my instance variables outside of the constructor.  This let's me look at the top of a class and get an idea for all properties and their access modifiers without having to read the code.

For example, I really don't like methods like this

```
// ...
// whole bunch of code
// ...
public function initialize() {
    $this->foo = array();
    // some other code to add some stuff to foo
}
```

Now, if I just look at the class, I can't be sure there is a variable foo even available.  If there is, I don't know if I have access to it from anywhere outside the instance.

If instead I have:

```
public $foo = array();
```

at the top of my class, I know that foo is an instance property, and that I can access it from elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

There are no performance implications. Stop obsessing over things that don't matter - concentrate on performance problems that ARE there: measure first, optimize only the top offenders.