# How to model a PHP Many to Many Relationship

Tags: php, model, many-to-many

I need to build an item System for one of our customers.
The item System has the following (given) database structure:

```
| item
+--------------------------
| id tinyint(4) primary key
| name varchar(30)

| attr
+--------------------------
| id tinyint(4) primary key
| name varchar(30)

| itemAttr
+--------------------------
| itemId foreign key
| attrid foreign key
| value varchar(255)
```

And I've got the class structure:

```
<?php

abstract class Item {
    private $id;

    private $name;  
}

class ShopItem extends Item {
    private $itemType;

    private $price;

    private $imageHref;

    private $description;   
}
```

Because it's a many to many relation, I could have X rows containing a single information about the "item".

How can I bundle / group the rows so that I can map the information to the model?

I need e.g. 20 different "ShopItems" for one page

**UPDATE**

I want to handle all Database Actions in one Query (that's what my task says...)
So there are going to be results like:

```
| id | name     | attrId | value |
+----+----------+--------+-------+
| 1  | Item1    | 1      | 1     |
| 1  | Item1    | 2      | Text  |
| 1  | Item1    | 3      | 100   |
```

And I have different search criteria:

The Item needs to have the the following attributes:
ItemType (attrId 1)
Description (attrId 2)
Price (attrId 3)

Otherwise I don't want to fetch this item out of the database

Answer (score 0):

One option (of several – as usual) is to store them in a map and access those attributes via a generic getter (using the attribute name as first argument) or to access them using magic functions.

```
<?php
abstract class Item {
    private $id;

    private $name;

    protected $attributes = array();

    /**
     * @param $name The attribute key/name
     * @return null|mixed returns NULL if the attribute was not set
     */
    public function getAttribute( $name ) {
        if( isset( $this->attributes[$name] ) ) {
            return $this->attributes[$name];
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Using [magic functions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php):

```
<?php
abstract class Item {
    private $id;

    private $name;

    protected $attributes = array();

    /**
     * @param $name The attribute key/name
     * @return null|mixed returns NULL if the attribute was not set
     */
    public function __get( $name ) {
        if( isset( $this->attributes[$name] ) ) {
            return $this->attributes[$name];
        }
        else {
            /* Trigger an error for unknown properties */
            $trace = debug_backtrace();
            trigger_error(
                'Undefined attribute: ' . $name .
                ' in ' . $trace[0]['file'] .
                ' line ' . $trace[0]['line'],
                E_USER_NOTICE);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would add an array of attributes as a member to your Item class. Best practise can be found here: [PHP5. Two ways of declaring an array as a class member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557673/php5-two-ways-of-declaring-an-array-as-a-class-member)

In database theory you need this pivot table to follow the principles of normalization, where nested relations are forbidden. But you don't really have this requirement in Php between classes.

Answer (score 0):

Basic class relations:

```
class Item
{
    private $id;
    private $name;

    public $attrs = array();

    public function addAttr(Attr &$attr) { $this->attrs[] = $attr; $attr->items[] = $this; }
    public function getAttrs() { return $this->attrs; }

    public function __construct($id, $name)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}

class Attr
{
    private $id;
    private $name;

    public $items = array();

    public function addItem(Item &$item) { $this->items[] = $item; $item->attrs[] = $attr; }
    public function getItems() { return $this->items; }

    public function __construct($id, $name)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}

$item1 = new Item(1, "I1");
$item2 = new Item(2, "I2");

$attr1 = new Attr(1, "A1");
$attr2 = new Attr(2, "A2");

$item1->addAttr($attr1);
$item1->addAttr($attr2);

var_dump($item1->getAttrs());
var_dump($attr1->getItems());
```

I recommend to use an ORM library.